# Convert from Class type to Reference class

Tags: java, interface

This question's background can be found from my previous question.

Previous question: http://tinyurl.com/chq4w7t

I have a interface `Comm` with a send function:

```
public interface Comm
{
    public int send(Socket socket, byte[] bytes);
}
```

I have various classes (`Server`, `Client`, `Serial`, etc.) which implements the interface `Comm`. I can pass these class objects as a parameter to another send function in another class which acts as a manager between the `Comm` objects and various plugins which are configurable to use one of these `Comm` classes as a communication medium.

(`Server`, `Client`, `Serial`, etc.) may be passed as parameter to the send function below

```
public void Send(Comm com, Socket socket, byte[] message)
{
    com.send(null, message);
}
```

From my previous question I have a `getClasses` function which returns a `Class[]` and takes a String as parameter. This is used to provide the different configuration options.

I use `Class.forName("Client");` for example to return a `Class` object for Client.

**Now finally my question is the following:**

How do I convert from `Class` to a `Comm` type? I made the following attempt for you to get an idea: (`cboxComm` is a test combobox for testing my code. It contains the class names for the `Comm` objects)

```
// Some code I have no idea how it works, an explanation would be awesome
// regarding the diamond syntax
Class<? extends Comm> classComm = Class.forName(cboxComm.getSelectedItem().toString());

// Error here, I don't know how to convert or cast it        
Comm com = classComm;

// Sending function as described above
send(com, null, null);
```

Comment: `Comm com = (Comm) classComm;` isin't this working? You should have a instanceof check though.

Comment: @Ankit: I certainly wouldn't expect it to!

Comment: Your comment regarding "the diamond syntax" doesn't make much sense - you're not *using* diamond syntax.

Comment: @JonSkeet: My bad, didn't noticed that. Upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm not very familiar to java, I meant by using <? extends `Comm`>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't convert from the `Class` object to an instance of the class. You need to create an instance, e.g. with the [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method:

```
Comm com = classComm.newInstance();
```

Note that this requires a public parameterless constructor in the class. Is that always the case in your code? If not, you'll need to fetch the appropriate constructor and invoke it using reflection, which will get a bit more complicated.

As an aside, I'm surprised this works at all for you:

```
Class<? extends Comm> classComm = Class.forName(...);
```

There's nothing really checking that the class returned by `forName` will implement `Comm`. I would have expected this to be required:

```
Class<?> classComm = Class.forName();
Comm comm = (Comm) classComm.newInstance();
```

At that point, the cast *will* perform the appropriate check.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just tested it. 
An InstantiationException is thrown at that point.

I trust this is because my class contructors take parameters? Haha

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html

Comment: I performed a test. I created contructors for each `Comm` object which takes no parameters. Your code works then :). I just have to figure out how that Reflection works.